# Image/text Hyperlinks- HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, footer

I am currently creating hyperlinked social media icons in the footer of my website. Each of the 3 images are seperate and eahc hyperlinking to a different social media. However the 'Copyright' text underneath the images in the footer is automatically hyperlinking to the link as the last image= Instagram.

How do I unlink that text? As i want it to just be displayed text not a hyperlink

```css
.Socials {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 30%;
    }

    #footer {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Big Shoulders Stencil Text', cursive;
    }
```

```html
      <div id="footer">
        <div class="Socials">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/studyatulster/">
          <img id="Facebook" src="Facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/UlsterUni?  ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor">
          <img id="Twitter" src="Twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ulsteruni/?hl=en">
          <img id="Instagram" src="Instagram.png" alt="Instagram">
        </div>
        <p>Belfast Virtual Shopping Centre - Copyright 2020</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Close your hyperlinks with a `</a>`.  For example:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/studyatulster/">
  <img id="Facebook" src="Facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
</a>
```

Otherwise the browser is trying to correct the markup structure for you, and it may not always guess correctly.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! Turns out I had my opening <a> and not my closing </a> so I added those in and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end the `<a>` tags in order for the "linking" to not continue.

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="Socials">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/studyatulster/">
      <img id="Facebook" src="Facebook.png" alt="Facebook"
    /></a>
    <a
      href="https://twitter.com/UlsterUni?  ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor"
    >
      <img id="Twitter" src="Twitter.png" alt="Twitter"
    /></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ulsteruni/?hl=en">
      <img id="Instagram" src="Instagram.png" alt="Instagram"
    /></a>
  </div>
  <p>Belfast Virtual Shopping Centre - Copyright 2020</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close your tags!

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/studyatulster/">
  <img id="Facebook" src="Facebook.png" alt="Facebook"/>
</a>
```

And if it does not require closing, like the image, you can put a slash in the opening tag, as showed in the code sample.